# Derivation of properties of multivariable Gaussian from Eigendecomposition of Covariance Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normal-distribution

I am following along on a [short lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eho8xH3E6mE) about the multivariable gaussian distribution. Right now it is talking about how we can eigendecompose the covariance matrix ${\Sigma}$.

If we set ${\Delta}^2$ to the part in the exponential of the multivariable gaussian that is NOT constant (since that's the only thing that changes the output of the Gaussian, since everything else is a constant), it can be shown that the ellipse formed by constant values of ${\Delta}^2$ can be broken down into...

[image]

I understand everything except for the declaration that ${\Delta}^2 = y_1^2/{\lambda}_1 + y_2^2/{\lambda}_2$. I am just wondering where that comes from.

Thanks, A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the author intents $y = (x - \mu) U$. What is written is a row vector by a row vector, which does not make sense.

By definition $y = (x - \mu) U$ and $\Delta^2 = (x - \mu) \Sigma^{-1} (x - \mu)^\top$ and $\Sigma = U \Lambda U^\top$. Therefore,
$$
\Delta^2 = (x - \mu) \Sigma^{-1} (x - \mu)^\top
= (x - \mu) U \Lambda^{-1} U^\top (x - \mu)^\top = y \Lambda^{-1} y^\top = \sum_i y_i^2 / \lambda_i\,,
$$
where in the second equality I used the fact that $(U\Lambda U^\top)^{-1} = U \Lambda^{-1} U^\top$. The third inequality is the definition of $y$ and the last because $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix with $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ on its diagonal and so its inverse has $\lambda_1^{-1}, \lambda_2^{-1}$ on its diagonal.